# Interrupt does not show anything

Tags: assembly

I am trying some x86 Assembly on Windows, and I'm having some troubles. A very simple program:

```
section .text
global start
start:  
    MOV DL, 'a' 
    MOV AH, 02H
    INT 21H 
    MOV AH, 4CH
    INT 21H
    end
```

doesn't show anything, although I call the 21h interrupt to show a character.
That's what I do:

```
nasm -f win32 f.asm
alink -subsys win -oPE -c -entry start f.obj
f
```

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int 21h` is  DOS interrupt and doesn't work for Windows. If you want to use Windows, you must use Windows API, if you want to use DOS, you must assemble and link it as a DOS Program.

Comment: Then I've to use a DOS emulator.

Comment: In 32bit windows you can still run DOS programs. If you are running a 64bit system, then you have to run it on an emulater as DOS is no longer supported directly.

Comment: No, I can not any longer because Windows does not support the old-style 16 bit DOS application since Windows has moved to the NT kernel. 
In addition, 2^16 bytes are a very small addressable memory.